# How to exclude obj folder from a copy task in VSTS build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have tried multiple combinations in the Contents section, but still, the everytime obj folder is copied to my build.

Here's my source directory structure
[image]

I have used following combinations for my `Contents` section:

1.
**\!(obj|V1Server.vshost.exe|V1Server.vshost.exe.config|*.pdb|*.xml|*.cache|*.cs|*.csproj|*.CopyComplete|*.ico|*.resx|*.resources|*.txt)
bin\$(BuildConfiguration)
bin\App.config

2.obj\!(*)

3.!(obj)

4.!(obj)\

What is wrong with my pattern matching syntax?

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to need below two lines to exclude obj folder in `contents` option:

```
**
!src\V1TCPIPService\obj\**
```

[image]

Comment: Does `**` denote all files to be copied from root directory?

Comment: Yes, if you want to copy part of files, you can specify the file which you want to copy.

Comment: @Sameer did you copy files and folders correctly by this pattern?

Answer (score 7):

Just use this code:

```
**
!**\obj\**
```